# get makefile output to directory above

Tags: c, makefile, directory, output

```
CC=gcc

CFLAGS=-Wall -g -std=c11 -c

LDFLAGS = -shared

BIN = ./bin/

SRC = ./src/

SRC1 = ./src/test1.c

SRC2 = ./src/test2.c

SRC_FILES = $(wildcard ./src/*.c)

program:

    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(SRC1) -Iinclude -o $(BIN)test1.so
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(SRC2) -Iinclude -o $(BIN)test2.so

test1:

    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(SRC1) -Iinclude -o $(BIN)test2.so

test2:

    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(SRC2) -Iinclude -o $(BIN)test2.so

cls:

    clear

clean:

    rm ./bin/*
```

so my folder set up is the root which is called temp, then inside that another folder called compile, within that is the the makefile, src, include, bin. what i need help doing is having the .so file output to temp instead of to bin but im not sure how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Just use the same technique that you used with BIN.

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(SRC2) -Iinclude -o ../test2.so
```